# Two layers with same CRS have widely different coordinates and scales, do not line up

Tags: qgis

I have two layers.

(1) Raster layer with flood inundation depths for Vietnam
(2) Shapefile layer with administrative boundaries for Vietnam

The two layers have the same projection (4326).

I load them both onto QGIS. The raster looks good and has appropriate coordinates (e.g. 100.96, 10.47) and scale (1:7,251,734). But the shapefile is really weird. Its coordinates are something ridiculous like (870842, 1503788) and its scale is also crazy at (1:-2,147,483,648).

Of course, the two layers do not line up.

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that a spatial reference misassignment is behind this question.  It is possible to associate an impossible spatial reference.  (I have done this.) The administrative boundary coordinates look like meters, not degrees - minutes.

-a look at the bounds for Vietnam here

spatatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3406/

is a place to start.

Then, trace back to the source for the administrative boundary to find the correct projected spatitial reference.

I hope this helps.

best regards,
Katie